# D3.js SVG image bounding box offset

Tags: javascript, html, d3.js, svg

I am attempting to fill a div with an svg image using D3.js. So far I have been able to center my image and watch it scale as I grow and shrink the browser window. However when attempting to dynamically find the bounding box of image I can only find the top,left properties of the canvas and the width of all the space no just my original image.

Here is a basic mock up of my problem:
http://jsfiddle.net/wnwfn/79/

```js
d3.select("#svgEmbed").append("image")
    .attr("xlink:href","http://www.clipartkid.com/images/32/square-clip-art-black-and-white-clipart-panda-free-clipart-images-UkJ6sF-clipart.png")
    .attr("width", "100%")
    .attr("height", "100%")
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/d3/3.3.12/d3.min.js"></script>
<p>
    <svg id="svgEmbed" height="100%" width="100%"    ></svg>
</p>
```

So my question is how can I find the top left position of the square image in this example? I've had a play using the .offset(), .getBBox() but I can't seem to get the values I am looking for.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your approach isn't going to work.  By setting the image width/height to `100%`, the image element will always be positioned at `[0,0]`.  If you know the pixel size of how you want the image to display, you can do something like this:

```js
var imgSize = 150;
var img = d3.select("#svgEmbed")
  .append("image")
  .attr("xlink:href", "http://www.clipartkid.com/images/32/square-clip-art-black-and-white-clipart-panda-free-clipart-images-UkJ6sF-clipart.png")
  .attr("x", "50%")
  .attr("width", imgSize)
  .attr("height", imgSize)
  .attr("transform", "translate(" + (-imgSize / 2) + ", 0)");

d3.select(window).on("resize", function(){
  console.log(img.node().getBBox());
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/d3/3.4.11/d3.min.js"></script>
<p>
  <svg id="svgEmbed" height="100%" width="100%"></svg>
</p>
```